# Reorder a table for/before a case/when clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a query, with some case When clause.

I use then , the function lead(or lag) to check other lines.

The problem is, I check it, in the order of the table, without order. So it will not be always in the good order in my result.

```
 CASE
          WHEN Lead(s.id_location, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY s.id_location) = s.id_location THEN  'at the same address '
          ELSE '\par \tab ' ||s.dir || '\par \tab '|| s.address || '\par \tab salle ' || s.lib_ || '\par \tab '|| s.etage  
        END AS adresscomplete,
```

I got a date associated that can order by. But
 the problem is that the wrong line can have the "at the same address" text, because I do not choose the order it made the lead(or lag).
So, This can be as result :

My direction, my address my salle .... at the same address 
or
at the same address .... My direction, my address my salle

The second is obvisouly wrong

Can I choose, before going into my case, to order the lines by date, so it will always the second, that will be with "at the same address" text.

This should be

My direction, my address my salle first date .... at the same address second date 
and not

at the same address date .... My direction, my address my salle second date

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks okay. Only make sure that you use the same order, when displaying your result records:

```
SELECT ...
  CASE 
    WHEN LAG(s.id_location) OVER (ORDER BY s.id_location) = s.id_location 
    THEN  'at the same address '
  ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY s.id_location; -- <== This is necessary to show your results ordered
```

EDIT: Why is it LEAD? You would want LAG to see wether the previous line had this address already in order to display 'at the same address'.

EDIT: To have it ordered by your date (and by location within date) use the following statement. I truncate the date in order to remove a time part in case there is any.

```
SELECT ...
  CASE 
    WHEN LAG(s.id_location) OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(s.thedate), s.id_location) = s.id_location 
    THEN  'at the same address '
  ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY TRUNC(s.thedate), s.id_location; -- <== This is necessary to show your results ordered
```

Comment: I can't order by location, because I want order by date, as I said in my first post.

Comment: What I am saying is: As 'at the same address' refers to the line before, it must be the line before you compare with. So have the _same_ order by in your LAG function as in the whole select.

Comment: I understnat what you mean but : if I change first date, to make it after the second date, then the result will be  `new first date at the same address ... new second date full address` , because the LAG function will not check the lines depending on the date... That is my problem.

Comment: No, just try it. You are confusing things. When you execute your select statement the rows are ordered. The select statement orders them to show you the rows in the order you desire and the LAG statement orders them to know what is the line before another. (And you will use the _same_ order, because you want to refer to the "line before" and not to the "line that would be before if we ordered differently". What are you talking about changing the date? The date cannot change in the middle of selection. And of course: each you change dates and select again, the result will be a bit different.

Comment: I think I wrong you, assuming all the SQL I give was enough. Add complete query in the question.

Comment: Look at your query. Is the order in SELECT and LAG the same or is it not? Again: Use the same ORDER BY in your query and your LAG function.

Comment: Oh, how blind I am. I was focusing on the ORDER BY in the select, totally forgetting the one in the `OVER`. Thank you.